# Reduce symfony2 database requests

Tags: php, symfony, caching, doctrine-orm

I'm developing a site with Symfony2.4 which stores some "semi-static" info in the database (such as addresses, telephones, social media URL's, etc...) to allow the client modify that data through backend.

The site works fine but I think it should be some way to reduce the accesses to the database for retrieving those data for every request (because is printed in all pages).

Is there any way to cache that data? Is a good practice store it in a user session the first time it enters the site?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use [APC](https://www.php.net/apc/) for instance.
Assuming you have `php-apc` extension installed and enabled (you can check it in `phpinfo`) this is all you need to do:

in your `config_prod.yml` (you don't want results to be cached in `dev` environment)

```
doctrine:
    orm:
        metadata_cache_driver: apc
        result_cache_driver: apc
        query_cache_driver: apc
```

and then in your query:

```
$queryBuilder
    (...)
    ->useQueryCache(true)
    ->useResultCache(true)
    (...)
```

First time you make this query it will fetch data from database. Next time it will fetch data from cache. You can also set lifetime of cache: [example](http://symfony.com/legacy/doc/more-with-symfony/1_4/en/08-Advanced-Doctrine-Usage#chapter_08_sub_sample_queries)

EDIT: Above link is to symfony 1.x documentation, however usage of `useQueryCache` and `useResultCache` are the same in symfony 1.x and Symfony2.x.

For bigger doc on Symfony2 Doctrine configuration check [this](http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/configuration/doctrine.html) link as @Francesco Casula mentioned

Comment: Thank you! Your answer is very accurate and is just what I'm searching for, but my hosting provider doesn't have the `php-apc` extension enabled... There is any other way to do it?

Comment: the provided link points to the Symfony1 documentation. this one is the correct link: http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/configuration/doctrine.html

Comment: My hosting provider has enabled apc in my server, so my question is answered. Thanks for your help.